# How to stub an object using Sinon?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, sinon, sinon-chai

I'm wondering if/how i can use Sinon to stub the object `mappedValues` nested in the function below:

```
function getValueFromObj(key) {
    var mappedValues = {
        "a": "aaa",
        "b": "bbb",
        "c": "ccc",
        "d": "ddd",
    };

    return mappedValues[key];
}
```

My goal for the test is not to check each value but rather just make sure that when passed a `key` a correctly corresponding value is returned and the value is not augmented in any way.

I *think* the best way to test this is to have the test stub `mappedValues` and then check the return value of `getValueFromObj` but i'm not sure how to actually stub the object.

Comment: You can use mappedValues.hasOwnProperty(key)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think is a good idea to use sinon for this purpose. I think you can simply write a test like this:

```
expect(getValueFromObj("a")).to.eql("aaa");
```

when this expectation (i use chai expect to write that) is satisfied you are sure that all work correctly.